# What is this shrub

Tags: identification, shrubs

I happened to photograph one of the shrubs that was wild around my home. Surprised to see it resemble somewhat closer to a cactus, however couldn't find help from the locals.

I am currently living in India, and if somebody could identify the plant i would be really thankful.[image]

Comment: I think the word "shrub" implies that the plant has some woody parts, but yours don't, so it is not a shrub, am I right?

Comment: It seems a sort of Carduus, or somethinf of Cynareae tribe. According wikipedia, there are no many species of Cynareae in India, so this could help you to find the exact species and report here.

Comment: @VividD Yes! Excuse me for my poor understanding

Comment: Looks like a [Milk Thistle](http://healthheathen.com/2015/02/16/milk-thistle-silybum-marianum-benefits-side-effects-silymarin-uses-research-findings/), do you have pictures of the flowers? Or any adult specimens?

Comment: No. It was cleaned up the next week. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Silybum marianum](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=varigated%20thistle%20&t=ffsb&iax=images&ia=images) The [Variegated thistle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silybum_marianum), or Milk thistle as b.nota states.
It grows in Australia. I've seen it in California. Wikipedia says

> Originally a native of Southern Europe through to Asia

That includes India.